# The informative value of a small sample

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In a regression setting, imagine you have a very highly statistically significant $(p<0.01)$ effect of covariate $x$ on a binary variable $y$. However the variable $y$ has many zeros and only a few ones. The sample size can be seen as large.

How does knowing that the there are many zeros affect your interpretation of the statistical significance of the coefficient, if at all? Put differently, should the information about the small sample size of ones make me more skeptical about significance in this regression?

Comment: How many data were there total? Does the result make basic sense in light of what is currently known about this topic?

Comment: @gung hi, large sample size. Not sure how to answ your 2nd question.

Comment: You can construct a confidence interval, that would help.

Comment: Large means very different things in different subdisciplines, some are impressed by 500 others need 5,000,000 or more before they are impressed.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But my question here is whether I should change my conclusions about the statistical significance of a coefficient depending on the number of observations being relatively small. That is: "small" is intended relative to the level of significance.